# Aliasing parts of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with a lot of arrays, and I'd like to know if there's a way to use aliasing so that operations using a subset of the array do not need to "reslice" the array each time the global array is updated.

For example:

```
values  = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000])
index   = np.array([2, 4, 8, 9])
sub_val = values[index]
```

This returns the following for sub_val:

```
sub_val = [300 500 900 1000]
```

If I change the original array:

```
values += 1
```

sub_val still returns:

```
sub_val = [300 500 900 1000]
```

instead of the desired:

```
sub_val = [301 501 901 1001]
```

Based on this, I'm assuming that all index/slice operations are creating a shallow copy. Is there a way to instead have sub_val be an alias of that subset of the array?

The goal is to be able to do this as efficiently as possible (The subset matrices are used for thousands of iterations).

Comment: I suppose you can create your own slice_view class to get that behaviour.

Comment: Not with that index.  Review docs on views v copies and basic v advanced indexing.

Comment: *basic* slicing returns a view and should be faster than *advanced* indexing

Comment: Is it possible to do basic slicing when the index values are non consecutive and may not have a standard step (not in the format, start: stop: interval)?

Comment: basic is supposed to be pretty fast, why do you mind it?

Comment: I would using basic slicing if I could, but my understanding is that basic slicing will not work if the slices are "random", i.e. non consecutive or not in specified intervals.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as `shallow copy` of a numpy array.  It's either a view or a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of an array are stored in a data buffer, but you never access that directly.  The array's indexing methods take care of that, using its `dtype`, `shape`, and `strides`.

A `view` has its own `shape` and `strides`, but shares the data buffer (possibly starting at a different point in the buffer).  Thus it 'sees' changes that have been made to the original.

But your 'random' indexing can't be expressed in terms of `shape` and `strides`.  So `numpy` has to make a copy - an array with its own data buffer (values copied from the original).  And that copy does not retain any record of how it was created (i.e. it does not store the index).

The suggest duplicate had answers that copied values from the original, and copied them back, but that doesn't save on any of the transaction costs that you fear.

My suggestion is to not worry about this indexing cost.  Assume `numpy` is performing this step as efficiently as possible.  Focus instead on reducing those `thousands of iterations`.